# Instant.io works but not my code

Tags: javascript, webtorrent

I have a problem when using webtorrent.min.js

I followed the instruction at  [Get Started](https://webtorrent.io/intro) but it does not load anything.

This is my code:

```js
var torrentId = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:209c8226b299b308beaf2b9cd3fb49212dbd13ec&dn=Tears+of+Steel&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.btorrent.xyz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.fastcast.nz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com'

var client = new WebTorrent()

// HTML elements
var $body = document.body
var $progressBar = document.querySelector('#progressBar')
var $numPeers = document.querySelector('#numPeers')
var $downloaded = document.querySelector('#downloaded')
var $total = document.querySelector('#total')
var $remaining = document.querySelector('#remaining')
var $uploadSpeed = document.querySelector('#uploadSpeed')
var $downloadSpeed = document.querySelector('#downloadSpeed')

// Download the torrent
client.add(torrentId, function(torrent) {
  // Torrents can contain many files. Let's use the .mp4 file
  var file = torrent.files.find(function(file) {
    return file.name.endsWith('.mp4')
  })

  // Stream the file in the browser
  //file.appendTo('#output')

  // Trigger statistics refresh
  torrent.on('done', onDone)
  setInterval(onProgress, 500)
  onProgress()

  // Statistics
  function onProgress() {
    // Peers
    $numPeers.innerHTML = torrent.numPeers + (torrent.numPeers === 1 ? ' peer' : ' peers')

    // Progress
    var percent = Math.round(torrent.progress * 100 * 100) / 100
    $progressBar.style.width = percent + '%'
    $downloaded.innerHTML = prettyBytes(torrent.downloaded)
    $total.innerHTML = prettyBytes(torrent.length)

    // Remaining time
    var remaining
    if (torrent.done) {
      remaining = 'Done.'
    } else {
      remaining = moment.duration(torrent.timeRemaining / 1000, 'seconds').humanize()
      remaining = remaining[0].toUpperCase() + remaining.substring(1) + ' remaining.'
    }
    $remaining.innerHTML = remaining

    // Speed rates
    $downloadSpeed.innerHTML = prettyBytes(torrent.downloadSpeed) + '/s'
    $uploadSpeed.innerHTML = prettyBytes(torrent.uploadSpeed) + '/s'
  }

  function onDone() {
    $body.className += ' is-seed'
    onProgress()
  }
})

// Human readable bytes util
function prettyBytes(num) {
  var exponent, unit, neg = num < 0,
    units = ['B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB']
  if (neg) num = -num
  if (num < 1) return (neg ? '-' : '') + num + ' B'
  exponent = Math.min(Math.floor(Math.log(num) / Math.log(1000)), units.length - 1)
  num = Number((num / Math.pow(1000, exponent)).toFixed(2))
  unit = units[exponent]
  return (neg ? '-' : '') + num + ' ' + unit
}
```

```css
#output video {
  width: 100%;
}

#progressBar {
  height: 5px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #35b44f;
  transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
}

body.is-seed .show-seed {
  display: inline;
}

body.is-seed .show-leech {
  display: none;
}

.show-seed {
  display: none;
}

#status code {
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.is-seed #hero {
  background-color: #154820;
  transition: .5s .5s background-color ease-in-out;
}

#hero {
  background-color: #2a3749;
}

#status {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 5px;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #30a247;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero">
  <div id="output">
    <div id="progressBar"></div>
    <!-- The video player will be added here -->
  </div>
  <!-- Statistics -->
  <div id="status">
    <div>
      <span class="show-leech">Downloading </span>
      <span class="show-seed">Seeding </span>
      <code>
            <!-- Informative link to the torrent file -->
            <a id="torrentLink" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:209c8226b299b308beaf2b9cd3fb49212dbd13ec&dn=Tears+of+Steel&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.btorrent.xyz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.fastcast.nz&tr=wss%3A%2F%2Ftracker.openwebtorrent.com">Tears of Steel</a>
          </code>
      <span class="show-leech"> from </span>
      <span class="show-seed"> to </span>
      <code id="numPeers">0 peers</code>.
    </div>
    <div>
      <code id="downloaded"></code> of <code id="total"></code> — <span id="remaining"></span><br/> &#x2198;
      <code id="downloadSpeed">0 b/s</code> / &#x2197;<code id="uploadSpeed">0 b/s</code>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Include the latest version of WebTorrent -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webtorrent/latest/webtorrent.min.js"></script>
<!-- Moment is used to show a human-readable remaining time -->
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

But when i run the hash with [Instant.io](https://instant.io/#209c8226b299b308beaf2b9cd3fb49212dbd13ec), it works like a charm.

Could anyone help me to find where I missing?

The movie is seeding via latest version of WebTorrent Desktop on Window 10 PC.

Thanks alot.

Comment: possible re bittorrent in the other client and webtorrent you are using dont know yet either.. have you checked your trackers?